# Grouping Python dictionary keys as a list and create a new dictionary with this list as a value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python dictionary

```
d = {1: 6, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 9, 5: 9, 6: 1}
```

Since the values in the above dictionary are not unique, I want to group the all the keys of unique values as a list and create a new dictionary as follows:

```
v = {6:[1], 1:[2, 3, 6], 9: [4, 5]}
```

Note the keys of new dictionary **v** should be sorted. I am finding it hard to visualize and implement this dictionary creation.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for ease:

```
from collections import defaultdict

v = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    v[value].append(key)
```

but you can do it with a bog-standard `dict` too, using [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
v = {}

for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    v.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
```

The above sorts keys *first*; sorting the values of the output dictionary later is much more cumbersome and inefficient.

If anyone would *not* need the output to be sorted, you can drop the `sorted()` call, and use *sets* (the keys in the input dictionary are guaranteed to be unique, so no information is lost):

```
v = {}

for key, value in d.items():
    v.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
```

to produce:

```
{6: {1}, 1: {2, 3, 6}, 9: {4, 5}}
```

(that the output of the set values is sorted is a coincidence, a side-effect of how hash values for integers are implemented; sets are unordered structures).

Comment: If you go with the defaultdict, but don't want the "default" behavior to continue after you initialize the dict, you can set the `default_factory` attribute to `None`.  Then your `defaultdict` will behave like a regular dict in nearly every way.

Comment: As a side note, I'm a huge fan of the way you sorted the items and not the values as would be most people's (or at least my) first instinct.  +1.

Comment: What is the `list` in 2nd line? It seems it will work by simply having `v = defaultdict()`

Comment: @clwen: no, that wouldn't work. `defaultdict()` takes a *factory function*, something that when called, produces a new object to insert into the dictionary when a key does not yet exist. Passing in `list` means that whenever a key doesn't exist yet, `v[value]` causes the defaultdict object to call `list()` and insert the result into the dictionary for that key. If you omit the factory function, `defaultdict` acts like a regular dictionary and raises a `KeyError` for missing keys.

Comment: "Sorting the values of the output dictionary later is much more cumbersome and inefficient." I'm nitpicking, but sorting the grouped lists is faster than sorting all the keys first, asymptotically speaking...

Answer (score 26):

If you don't actually need a `dict` at the end of the day, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for k, v in groupby(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)), itemgetter(1)):
    print(k, list(map(itemgetter(0), v)))
```

Of course, you could use this to construct a dict if you really wanted to:

```
{
    k: list(map(itemgetter(0), v))
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)), itemgetter(1))
}
```

But at that point, you're probably better off using Martijn's defaultdict solution.