# python list comprehension: gathering duplicate columns

Tags: python

I have a sorted list of lists that contain duplicate first elements.
Currently I'm iterating over it to get the solution.

```
[['5th ave', 111, -30.00, 38.00],
['5th ave', 222, -30.00, 33.00],
['6th ave', 2224, -32.00, 34.90]]
```

I'd like an elegant list comprehension to convert this to a list of lists based on the first element:

`['5th ave',  [[111, -30.00, 38.00] , [222, -30.00, 33.00]]`

Thanks

Comment: [A very close SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this).

Comment: Why, exactly, do you want a solution in the form of a list comprehension?

Comment: Would it be all right if it were a dictionary?

Comment: was hoping to keep the sorted order and keep it a list.

Comment: @user1550052 Updated my solution. Please check.

Comment: @user1550052 Mine is a hybrid solution now. Please check.

Comment: thanks for all the solutions. to answer @tom10, i was looking to see if a one liner was possible. no real reason other than my head was about to explode trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) really is the way to go, but I feel it might be slower which is why I came up with this:

```
from itertools import imap

def RemDup(L):
    ListComp = {}
    for sublist in L:
        try: ListComp[sublist[0]].append(sublist[1:])
        except KeyError: ListComp[sublist[0]] = [sublist[1:]]
    return imap( list, ListComp.items() )

DupList = [['5th ave', 111, -30.00, 38.00],
['5th ave', 222, -30.00, 33.00],
['6th ave', 2224, -32.00, 34.90]]

print [ uniq for uniq in RemDup(DupList) ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a job for [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> L = [['5th ave', 111, -30.00, 38.00],
... ['5th ave', 222, -30.00, 33.00],
... ['6th ave', 2224, -32.00, 34.90]]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for sublist in L:
...     d[sublist[0]].append(sublist[1:])
... 
>>> print d.items()
[('5th ave', [[111, -30.0, 38.0], [222, -30.0, 33.0]]), ('6th ave', [[2224, -32.0, 34.9]])]
```

There's absolutely no reason to have a list comprehension. Just because it's less lines does not mean it's more pythonic.

Comment: You beat me to this , but the war is not over yet! :P Great answer though.

Comment: just a joke. thing this solution breaks the sort. i was hoping to keep it in a list and still sorted.

Comment: Why `defaultdict` and why not `setdefault` in ordinary `dict`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I've never used a setdefault before. Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483520/use-cases-for-the-setdefault-dict-method , it seems defaultdict replaces it for the majority of cases

Comment: @user1550052 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python May help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['5th ave', 111, -30.00, 38.00],
['5th ave', 222, -30.00, 33.00],
['6th ave', 2224, -32.00, 34.90]]

previous   = ""
listOfData = []
result     = []
for currentItem in data:
    if currentItem[0] != previous:
        if listOfData:
            result.append([previous, listOfData])
            listOfData = []
        previous = currentItem[0]
    listOfData.append(currentItem[1:])

if listOfData:
    result.append([previous, listOfData])

print result
```

**Output**

```
[['5th ave', [[111, -30.0, 38.0], [222, -30.0, 33.0]]], ['6th ave', [[2224, -32.0, 34.9]]]]
```

This maintains the order as well.

**Edit:**

With `defaultdict` I could reduce few lines

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['5th ave', 111, -30.00, 38.00],
['5th ave', 222, -30.00, 33.00],
['6th ave', 2224, -32.00, 34.90]]

unique, Map = [], defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    if item[0] not in unique: unique.append(item[0])
    Map[item[0]].append(item[1:])
print [(item, Map[item]) for item in unique]
```

This still maintains order.

Comment: You should really only use upper case letters at the beginning of variable names for classes

Comment: @Haidro I updated the solution. I prefer naming the variables this way. Is there any specific reason why we should use uppercase letters only at the beginning?

Comment: thanks this is similar to what i was doing. just wanted to see if it was possible with a list comprehension.

Comment: have a look at [the PEP 8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) ;)