# How to compare values inside a dictionary to fill up sets()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

```
dico = {"dico":   {1:"bailler",2:"bailler",3:"percer",4:"calculer",5:"calculer",6:"trouer",7:"bailler",8:"découvrir",9:"bailler",10:"miser",11:"trouer",12:"changer"}}
```

I have a big dictionary of dictionaries like that. I want to put identic elements together in sets. So create a kind of condition which will say if the values of `"dico"` are equal put them in a `set()`:

```
b=[set(1,2,7,9),set(3),set(4,5),set(6,11),set(8),set(10),set(12)]
```

I don't know if that question has already been asked but as a new pythonner I don't have all the keys... ^^

Thank you for you answers

Comment: You cannot put equal items in a set (well, you can, but it won't affect the set). Sets work exactly the other way round.

Comment: This looks like a similar problem to this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this)

Answer (score 1):

I would reverse your dictionary and have the value a `set()`, then return all the values.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>>my_dict= {"dico":   {1:"bailler",2:"bailler",3:"percer",4:"calculer",5:"calculer",6:"trouer",7:"bailler",8:"découvrir",9:"bailler",10:"miser",11:"trouer",12:"changer"}}
>>> my_other_dict = defaultdict(set)
>>> for dict_name,sub_dict in my_dict.iteritems():
    for k,v in sub_dict.iteritems():
        my_other_dict[v].add(k) #the value, i.e. "bailler" is now the key
                                 #e.g. {"bailler":set([1,2,9,7]),...


>>> [v for k,v in my_other_dict.iteritems()]
[set([8]), set([1, 2, 9, 7]), set([3]), set([4, 5]), set([12]), set([11, 6]), set([10])]
```

Of course as cynddl has pointed out, if your index in a list will always be the "key", simply enumerate a list and you won't have to store original data as a dictionary, nor use `sets()` as indices are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your data this way:

```
dico = ["bailler", "bailler", "percer", "calculer", "calculer", "trouer", "bailler", "découvrir", "bailler", "miser", "trouer", "changer"]
```

If you want to count the number of identic elements, use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
counter=collections.Counter(dico)
print(counter)
```

which returns a `Counter` object:

```
Counter({'bailler': 4, 'calculer': 2, 'trouer': 2, 'd\xc3\xa9couvrir': 1, 'percer': 1, 'changer': 1, 'miser': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dict.setdefault()` method can be handy for tasks like this, as well as `dict.items()` which iterates through the `(key, value)` pairs of the dictionary.

```
>>> dico = {"dico":   {1:"bailler",2:"bailler",3:"percer",4:"calculer",5:"calcul
er",6:"trouer",7:"bailler",8:"découvrir",9:"bailler",10:"miser",11:"trouer",12:"
changer"}}
>>> newdict = {}
>>> for k, subdict in dico.items():
...     newdict[k] = {}
...     for subk, subv in subdict.items():
...         newdict[k].setdefault(subv, set()).add(subk)
...
>>> newdict
{'dico': {'bailler': {1, 2, 9, 7}, 'miser': {10}, 'découvrir': {8}, 'calculer':
{4, 5}, 'changer': {12}, 'percer': {3}, 'trouer': {11, 6}}}
>>> newdict['dico'].values()
dict_values([{1, 2, 9, 7}, {10}, {8}, {4, 5}, {12}, {3}, {11, 6}])
```