# Python - combining list of dictionaries by specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that represent variations of an item in a retail catalog:

```
[   
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Blue", "size": "Small" },
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Blue", "size": "Medium" },
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Blue", "size": "Large" },
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Red", "size": "Small" },
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Red", "size": "Large" },
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Green", "size": "Small" }
]
```

I would like to combine the list so that I end up with only one dictionary per color variation, and that the sizes available for each variation are grouped into a list, like so:

```
[
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Blue", "size": ["Small", "Medium", "Large"] },
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Red", "size": ["Small", "Large"] },
    { "product_name": "Sleeveless Sheath Dress", "brand": "BCBG", "color": "Green", "size": ["Small"] }
]
```

What's the most elegant/Pythonic way to accomplish that?

Comment: Or may be that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this.

Comment: yep! `itertools.groupby(lst, operator.itemgetter("product_name", "brand", "color"))`

Comment: @alecxe I don't think that's quite the same use case. In that case, the desired outcome would be to combine all key values - in my case I need to keep the color variations separate and only combine the sizes.

Comment: @AdamSmith your solution doesn't return a list - is there another step to get back the list I specified in my question?

Comment: @alexce can you please reopen this question since I explained to you why it's a different use case?

Comment: @KeepingItClassy I don't agree that it's a different use case, this is properly marked as a duplicate. Try `[{"product_name": groupinfo[0], "brand": groupinfo[1], "color": groupinfo[2], "sizes": [d['size'] for d in items]} for groupinfo, items in groups]` after `groups = itertools.groupby(...)` above

Comment: @AdamSmith, that did the trick, thank you! As a beginner it's very difficult for me to abstract specific use cases to general concepts. Apologies for the spam.

Comment: @KeepingItClassy that wasn't a simple comprehension. It's a list comprehension inside a dict value of another list comprehension. Your specific case was just not as simple as the usual general cases :)

Comment: @AdamSmith thank you for understanding :)