# Getting error when trying to groupby list of dictionaries python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388842/python-combining-list-of-dictionaries-by-specific-key?noredirect=1&lq=1) question. But I'm getting key error because not all of the lists are created equally.. I'm not sure what the best course of action would be for my case.

My list of dicts are dynamic and I'm trying to match up key/value of 'id'.

An example list is:

```
    data_keys: [[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 436,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'Start' to 'GetCallerDetail'"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 565,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'apn_match: ',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'Greeting' to 'apn_match'"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 571,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'apn_match: ',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension: Ifthefirst5lettersofthestreetnameforyourserviceaddressare[spellfirst5lettersofRAD.ServiceAddressStreetNamee.g.M-A-P-L-E]?press1.Otherwise,
        press2.',
        'content': ''
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension'"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 571,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'apn_match: ',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension: Ifthefirst5lettersofthestreetnameforyourserviceaddressare[spellfirst5lettersofRAD.ServiceAddressStreetNamee.g.M-A-P-L-E]?press1.Otherwise,
        press2.',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension: Again;ifthefirst5lettersofthestreetnameforyourserviceaddressare[spellfirst5lettersofRAD.ServiceAddressStreetNamee.g.M-A-P-L-E]?press1.Otherwise,
        press2.',
        'content': 'wait'
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', No Input & Recover"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 571,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'apn_match: ',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension: Ifthefirst5lettersofthestreetnameforyourserviceaddressare[spellfirst5lettersofRAD.ServiceAddressStreetNamee.g.M-A-P-L-E]?press1.Otherwise,
        press2.',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtensionNM1: Again;ifthefirst5lettersofthestreetnameforyourserviceaddressare[spellfirst5lettersofRAD.ServiceAddressStreetNamee.g.M-A-P-L-E]?press1.Otherwise,
        press2.',
        'content': 'press8'
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', No Match & Recover"
}],
[{
    'tcs_cannot_route': 'Thisedgecannotberouted,
    OnFailGoToempty',
    'id': 571,
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', No Input 3 Times Fail"
}],
[{
    'tcs_cannot_route': 'Thisedgecannotberouted,
    OnFailGoToempty',
    'id': 571,
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', No Match 3 Times Fail"
}],
[{
    'tcs_cannot_route': 'Thisedgecannotberouted,
    OnFailGoToempty',
    'id': 571,
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', No Input or No Match 3 Times Fail"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 571,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'apn_match: ',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension: Ifthefirst5lettersofthestreetnameforyourserviceaddressare[spellfirst5lettersofRAD.ServiceAddressStreetNamee.g.M-A-P-L-E]?press1.Otherwise,
        press2.',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension: ',
        'content': 'Novalidinputs'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtensionCNI1: ',
        'content': 'wait'
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', Confirm No Input & Recover"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 571,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'apn_match: ',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension: Ifthefirst5lettersofthestreetnameforyourserviceaddressare[spellfirst5lettersofRAD.ServiceAddressStreetNamee.g.M-A-P-L-E]?press1.Otherwise,
        press2.',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension: ',
        'content': 'Novalidinputs'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtensionCNM1: ',
        'content': 'press1'
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', Confirm No Match & Recover"
}],
[{
    'tcs_cannot_route': 'Thisedgecannotberouted,
    OnFailGoToempty',
    'id': 571,
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', Confirm No Input 3 Times Fail"
}],
[{
    'tcs_cannot_route': 'Thisedgecannotberouted,
    OnFailGoToempty',
    'id': 571,
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', Confirm No Match 3 Times Fail"
}],
[{
    'tcs_cannot_route': 'Thisedgecannotberouted,
    OnFailGoToempty',
    'id': 571,
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'ConfirmStreetNameIDV~NodeExtension', Confirm No Input or No Match 3 Times Fail"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': [567],
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'no_apn_match: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'AskDOB: ',
        'content': ''
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'no_apn_match' to 'AskDOB'"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 566,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'no_apn_match: ',
        'content': ''
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'Greeting' to 'no_apn_match'"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 564,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'Greeting'"
}],
[{
    'pre_conditions': [],
    'id': 568,
    'tc_steps': [{
        'expected': 'Enter_APN: PleaseentertheAPN',
        'content': 'APN: 8552929487,
        HollyBrowser: ,
        '
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_Test_Date: Pleaseenterthedate',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Enter_ANI: ',
        'content': ''
    },
    {
        'expected': 'Greeting: ',
        'content': 'press*'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'apn_match: ',
        'content': 'press4025554244'
    },
    {
        'expected': 'AskDOB: ',
        'content': ''
    }],
    'title': "Route from 'apn_match' to 'AskDOB'"
}]]
```

I'd like to end up with only 7 (in this case) dicts in this list

Here's my code for this specific task:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
groups = groupby(data_keys, itemgetter('id', 'title', 'pre_conditions', 'tc_steps', 'tcs_cannot_route'))

edge_data = [{'id': groupinfo[0], 'title': groupinfo[1], 'pre_conditions': groupinfo[2], 'tc_steps': groupinfo[3], 'tcs_cannot_route': groupinfo[4]} for groupinfo, items in groups]

print(edge_data)
```

Comment: So what is the error and what is the desired output?

Comment: @vincentmajor   It's a KeyError due to mismatched keys in the dictionaries. I'm trying to get a solution as to how this can be done if groupby isn't the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues spotted in the code above:

1. You're using `"tc_step"` in `itemgetter` while the key is `"tc_steps"`
2. You're using `"tcs_cannot_route"` while this key doesn't exist in some records

There might be other issues as well.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the tc_steps -- I understand the issue is because I don't have the same keys in all the dictionaries. I'm trying to sort out how this can be done? groupby might not be the solution...

Comment: In that case I suggest that you'll post a *new* question showing your data and what is the expected output of processing it. Here you focus on the "how" instead of "what you want to achieve" which seems to lead to a dead end.