# List of dicts: Getting list of matching dictionary based on id

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get the matching IDs and store the data into one list. I have a list of dictionaries:

```
list = [
            {'id':'123','name':'Jason','location': 'McHale'},
            {'id':'432','name':'Tom','location': 'Sydney'},
            {'id':'123','name':'Jason','location':'Tompson Hall'}
       ]
```

Expected output would be something like

```
# {'id':'123','name':'Jason','location': ['McHale', 'Tompson Hall']},
# {'id':'432','name':'Tom','location': 'Sydney'},
```

How can I get matching data based on dict ID value? I've tried:

```
for item in mylist:
    list2 = []
    row = any(list['id'] == list.id for id in list)
    list2.append(row)
```

This doesn't work (it throws: `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`). How can I get all items with the same ID and store into one dict?

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're iterating through the list of dictionaries in your for loop, but never referencing the dictionaries, which you're storing in `item`. I think when you wrote `list[id]` you mean `item[id]`.

Second, `any()` returns a boolean (true or false), which isn't what you want. Instead, maybe try `row = [dic for dic in list if dic['id'] == item['id']]`

Third, if you define list2 within your for loop, it will go away every iteration. Move `list2 = []` before the for loop.

That should give you a good start. Remember that `row` is just a list of all dictionaries that have the same id.

Comment: Third makes complete sense... But everything else is confusing me... I'm looping through the list to get every dictionary... then checking for matching ids. if matching then do stuff. Your solution seems to be throwing `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`.... I come from a javascript background, so while I understand what needs to be done. I'm having a hard time with syntax

Comment: You are getting that error because `list` is a keyword for a list object -- not a good name for a variable because it confuses the compiler. Try renaming `list` to something else.

Comment: i also had to change `[dic for dic in mylist if dic.id == item.id]`

Answer (score 1):

Given this input

```
mylist = [
            {'id':'123','name':'Jason','location': 'McHale'},
            {'id':'432','name':'Tom','location': 'Sydney'},
            {'id':'123','name':'Jason','location':'Tompson Hall'}
       ]
```

You can just extract it with a comprehension

```
matched = [d for d in mylist if d['id'] == '123']
```

Then you want to merge the locations. Assuming `matched` is not empty

```
final = matched[0]
final['location'] = [d['location'] for d in matched]
```

Here it is in the interpreter

```
In [1]: mylist = [
   ...:                 {'id':'123','name':'Jason','location': 'McHale'},
   ...:                 {'id':'432','name':'Tom','location': 'Sydney'},
   ...:                 {'id':'123','name':'Jason','location':'Tompson Hall'}
   ...:            ]

In [2]: matched = [d for d in mylist if d['id'] == '123']    
In [3]: final=matched[0]
In [4]: final['location'] = [d['location'] for d in matched]
In [5]: final
Out[5]: {'id': '123', 'location': ['McHale', 'Tompson Hall'], 'name': 'Jason'}
```

Obviously, you'd want to replace `'123'` with a variable holding the desired `id` value.

Wrapping it all up in a function:

```
def merge_all(df):
    ids = {d['id'] for d in df}
    result = []
    for id in ids:
        matches = [d for d in df if d['id'] == id]
        combined = matches[0]
        combined['location'] = [d['location'] for d in matches]
        result.append(combined)
    return result
```

Also, please don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows the builtin `list` class.

Answer (score 1):

I would use kdopen's approach along with a merging method after converting the dictionary entries I expect to become lists into lists.  Of course if you want to avoid redundancy then make them sets.

```
mylist = [
            {'id':'123','name':['Jason'],'location': ['McHale']},
            {'id':'432','name':['Tom'],'location': ['Sydney']},
            {'id':'123','name':['Jason'],'location':['Tompson Hall']}
       ]


def merge(mylist,ID):
    matches = [d for d in mylist if d['id']== ID]

    shell = {'id':ID,'name':[],'location':[]}

    for m in matches:
        shell['name']+=m['name']    
        shell['location']+=m['location']
        mylist.remove(m)

    mylist.append(shell)
    return mylist

updated_list = merge(mylist,'123')
```

Comment: I really like this solution alot. heads up: name would be a string. i'll try this out right now :D