# Sort a list by frequency and value

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the following problem: a function takes a list A. The results must be a ordered list of list. Each list contains the elements which have the same frequency in the original list A.

Example:

```
Input: [3, 1, 2, 2, 4]
Output: [[1, 3, 4], [2, 2]]
```

I managed to sort the initial list A and determine how the frequency of an element.
However, I do not know how to split the original list A based on the frequencies.

My code:

```
def customSort(arr):
    counter = Counter(arr)
    y = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (counter[x], x))
    print(y)
    x = Counter(arr)
    a = sorted(x.values())
    print()

customSort([3,1,2,2,4])
```

My current output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: What would be the output for `[1,3,3,3]`? `[[1],[3,3,3]]` or `[[1], [], [3,3,3]]`?

Comment: What about `[3, 2, 3, 2]`? What order would you expect?

Comment: The output for [1,3,3,3] would be [[1],[3,3,3]]. The output for [3, 2, 3, 2] would be [[2,2],[3,3]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` of lists and iterate your `Counter`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def customSort(arr):
    counter = Counter(arr)
    dd = defaultdict(list)
    for value, count in counter.items():
        dd[count].extend([value]*count)
    return dd

res = customSort([3,1,2,2,4])
# defaultdict(list, {1: [3, 1, 4], 2: [2, 2]})
```

This gives additional information, i.e. the key represents how many times the values in the lists are seen. If you require a list of lists, you can simply access values:

```
res = list(res.values())
# [[3, 1, 4], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing the grunt work suggested by Scott Hunter (Python 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Counter

def custom_sort(arr):
  v = {}
  for key, value in sorted(Counter(arr).items()):
    v.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
  return [v * k for k,v in v.items()]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(custom_sort([3, 1, 2, 2, 4])) # [[1, 3, 4], [2, 2]]
```

For Python 2.7 or lower use `iteritems()` instead of `items()`

Partially taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15751984)

Answer (score 2):

Having sorted the list as you do:

```
counter = Counter(x)
y = sorted(x, key=lambda x: (counter[x], x))
#[1, 3, 4, 2, 2]
```

You could then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), using the result from `Counter(x)` in the `key` argument to create groups according to the counts:

```
[list(v) for k,v in groupby(y, key = lambda x: counter[x])]
#[[1, 3, 4], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Find your maximum frequency, and create a list of that many empty lists.
2. Loop over your values, and add each to the element of the above corresponding to its frequency.

There might be something in `Collections` that does at least part of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of the same theme, using a `Counter` to get the counts and then inserting the elements into the respective position in the result list-of-lists. This retains the original order of the elemens (does not group same elements together) and keeps empty lists for absent counts.

```
>>> lst = [1,4,2,3,4,3,2,5,4,4]
>>> import collections
>>> counts = collections.Counter(lst)
>>> res = [[] for _ in range(max(counts.values()))]
>>> for x in lst:
...     res[counts[x]-1].append(x)
...     
>>> res
[[1, 5], [2, 3, 3, 2], [], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but with plain Python:

```
test = [3, 1, 2, 2, 4]

def my_sort(arr):
    count = {}
    for x in arr:
        if x in count:
            count[x] += 1
        else:
            count[x] = 0


    max_frequency = max(count.values()) + 1
    res = [[] for i in range(max_frequency)]

    for k,v in count.items():
        for j in range(v + 1):
            res[v].append(k)
    return res

print(my_sort(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only Pythons built-in functions, no imports and a single for loop.

```
l1= []
l2 = []
def customSort(mylist):
    sl = sorted(mylist)
    for i in sl:
        n = sl.count(i)
        if n > 1:
            l1.append(i)
        if i not in l1:
            l2.append(i)
    return [l2, l1]

print(customSort([3, 1, 2, 2, 4]))
```

Output:

> [[1, 3, 4], [2, 2]]