# Python Questions | Is there a bug with test scores for code developed on https://www.testdome.com

Tags: python

Question on [Test Dome](https://www.testdome.com/d/python-interview-questions/9).

Implement a group_by_owners function that:

Accepts a dictionary containing the file owner name for each file name.

Returns a dictionary containing a list of file names for each owner name, in any order.

For example, for dictionary `{'Input.txt': 'Randy', 'Code.py': 'Stan', 'Output.txt': 'Randy'}` the `group_by_owners` function should return `{'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}`.

When I run the below code that I developed while doing the example test I got 0% score by their online application and if you run the below code in your IDE it outputs correct transformed dictionary.

Why is their site not giving marks for the developed tests is this a bug with their algorithms that detect if the code is correct on their site?  Or am I doing something incorrectly here?

My understanding of Python is approx. 2 years experience.

```
'''Find all unique names given a dict'''
def getUniqueNames(file):
    file_owner_names = []
    for file_type, file_o in file.items():
        if file_o not in file_owner_names:
             file_owner_names.append(file_o)

     return file_owner_names

'''Get a list of files for an owner given a dict and owner'''
def getFileArray(file, file_owner):
    file_type_names = []
    for file_t, file_o in file.items():
        if file_o == file_owner:
            if file_t not in file_type_names:
                file_type_names.append(file_t)

    return file_type_names

'''Learned to used the dict'''
def group_by_owners(files_dict):
     new_file = {}
     i = 0
     file_owner_names = getUniqueNames(files_dict)
     for file_owner_name in file_owner_names:
         if i != len(file_owner_names):
              if (i < len(file_owner_names)):
                 new_file[file_owner_name] = str(getFileArray(files_dict, 
                 file_owner_name))
                 i = i + 1

return new_file


files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'HomeController.py': 'Randy',
    'Output.txt': 'Jeff',
    'SearchController.py': 'Rafeena',
    'ABTest.py': 'Nicholas',
    'SQL.py':'Nicholas'
 }

 print(group_by_owners(files))
```

Output of the above python script:

```py
{'Randy': "['Input.txt', 'HomeController.py']", 'Stan': "['Code.py']", 'Jeff': "['Output.txt']", 'Rafeena': "['SearchController.py']", 'Nicholas': "['ABTest.py', 'SQL.py']"}
```

Comment: Your output differs from the expected result. What should be lists are strings.

Comment: Thanks again for your response and solution.  I have removed the str() which was a issue.

Comment: Seems like **TestDome.com** Does not give points on tests for partial solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I think your problem is that you should change

```py
new_file[file_owner_name] = str(getFileArray(files_dict, file_owner_name))
```

to

```py
new_file[file_owner_name] = getFileArray(files_dict, file_owner_name)
```

by removing the call to `str`.

The output should then be:

```
{'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'HomeController.py'], 'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Jeff': ['Output.txt'], 'Rafeena': ['SearchController.py'], 'Nicholas': ['ABTest.py', 'SQL.py']}
```

Notice the lack of quotation marks around the lists.

Comment: Thanks Solomon Ucko... the str() is the issue.  Always learning something new.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2480313 Glad I could teach you something! [If you think this answer is the best, you can "accept" it by clicking on the checkmark next to it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You can use defaultdict from collections. Defaultdict takes care of adding new key.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = {'Input.txt': 'Randy', 'Code.py': 'Stan', 'Output.txt': 'Randy'}
o = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items():
    o[v] += [k]
print(dict(o))
# prints {'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly* answering your question, but this solution uses a standard dictionary.

```
def group_by_owners(files):
    grouped_files = {}

    for key, value in sorted(files.items()):
        grouped_files.setdefault(value, []).append(key)

    return grouped_files

#prints {'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt']}
```

I based my answer on an example found here: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following simple approach as well to get the required result

```
def group_by_owners(files):
    my_dict = {}
    for key,value in files.items():
        if value in my_dict:
            my_dict[value].append(key)
        else:
            my_dict[value] = [key]
    return my_dict

files = {'Input.txt': 'Randy', 'Code.py': 'Stan', 'Output.txt': 'Randy'}
print(group_by_owners(files))
# Prints {'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {'Input.txt': 'Randy', 'Code.py': 'Stan', 'Output.txt': 'Randy'}

d1 ={}

for key, value in d.items():
    
    if value in d1:
        d1[value].append(key)
    else:
        d1[value]=[key]
print(d1)
```

Output :

```
{'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```