# Sorted set list by dict value and group by names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to name the question title well, but it's complicated. So will be better if I give you an example. I have something like this:

```
[{'level': 4, 'name': 'Docker'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'Python'}, {'level': 3, 'name': 'JavaScript'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'HTML'}]
```

and I wish to get this:

```
[{'level': 4, 'name': ['Docker']}, {'level': 3, 'name': ['JavaScript']}, {'level': 1, 'name': ['Python', 'HTML']}]
```

I sorted an list by dictionary values with `powers.sort(key=lambda x: x['level'], reverse=True)` and got this which imo is close to solution.

```
[{'level': 4, 'name': 'Docker'}, {'level': 3, 'name': 'JavaScript'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'Python'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'HTML'}]
```

I'll be grateful with any help to group `names` by `level`!

Comment: you need a defaultdict(list) for this.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa nothing happens. First I have to sort by level and then group names

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Could you write how would you do that?

Comment: You should look at this [resolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one commenter says you can do this with `defaultdict` :

```
from collections import defaultdict

lang_list = [{'level': 4, 'name': 'Docker'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'Python'}, {'level': 3, 'name': 'JavaScript'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'HTML'}]

lvl_dict = defaultdict(list)
for d in lang_list:
    lvl_dict[d['level']].append(d['name'])

lvl_list = [{'level': k, 'name': v} for k, v in lvl_dict.items()]

lvl_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['level'], reverse=True)
[{'level': 4, 'name': ['Docker']}, {'level': 3, 'name': ['JavaScript']}, {'level': 1, 'name': ['Python', 'HTML']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are *only* sorting; grouping is another explicit operation.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> powers = [{'level': 4, 'name': 'Docker'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'Python'}, {'level': 3, 'name': 'JavaScript'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'HTML'}]
>>> get_level = itemgetter('level')
>>> get_name = itemgetter('name')
>>> def sort_and_group(lst, getter):
...   return groupby(sorted(lst, key=getter), getter)
...
>>> pprint([dict(level=k, name=list(map(get_name, v))) for k, v in sort_and_group(powers, get_level)])
[{'level': 1, 'name': ['Python', 'HTML']},
 {'level': 3, 'name': ['JavaScript']},
 {'level': 4, 'name': ['Docker']}]
```

In most cases, you want a single group for each common attribute, so sorting by the same attribute prior to grouping is common.

Answer (score 0):

using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [{'level': 4, 'name': 'Docker'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'Python'}, {'level': 3, 'name': 'JavaScript'}, {'level': 1, 'name': 'HTML'}]

res = (pd.DataFrame(a).groupby('level')['name']
                      .apply(list).reset_index(name='name')
                      .sort_values('level',ascending=False)
                      .to_dict('records'))
```