# Splitting a dictionary into a list of dictionary based on overlapping values

Tags: python, dictionary, coordinates

I have a dictionary with chromosomal coordinates, like the following example:

```
First_dict = {Key1: ['chr10', 19010495, 19014590, 19014064],
Key2: ['chr10', 19010495, 19014658],
Key3: ['chr10', 19010502, 19014641],
Key4: ['chr10', 37375766, 37377526],
Key5: ['chr10', 76310389, 76315990, 76312224, 76312963],
Key6: ['chr11', 14806147, 14814006]}
```

I would like to create a list of dictionaries, where those current keys with the minimum and maximum of the chromosomal coordinates (dictionary values) are overlapping with lets say at least a 1000, are grouped together into a new dictionary and the rest are separate dictionaries within the new list.

So ideally something like:

```
New_list = 
[{Key1: ['chr10', 19010495, 19014590, 19014064],Key2: ['chr10', 19010495, 19014658], Key3: ['chr10', 19010502, 19014641]}, 
{Key4: ['chr10', 37375766, 37377526]},
{Key5: ['chr10', 76310389, 76315990, 76312224, 76312963]},
{Key6: ['chr11', 14806147, 14814006]}]
```

Where key1, key2 and key3 are grouped together as a new dictionary within New_list since their chromosomal coordinates are overlapping, and key4, key5, key6 are individual dictionaries with New_list, since they arent overlapping at all.

My initial idea was to separate “First_dict” into a list of dictionaries using

```
[{k: v} for (k, v) in First_dict.items()]
```

And then iterate through each dict to compare the minimum and maximum values to the previous dictionary to check for overlap and then create a new list. But i have several problems, which i cant get my head around.

I’ve also looked for other questions grouping dictionaries together, like in the question: 
[Grouping Python dictionary keys as a list and create a new dictionary with this list as a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this)

But my problem is my vales aren’t always exactly the same, as the example above. And i also have to consider the chromosomes when thinking about the overlap.

Could anyone help with this, or come up with a suggestion to try? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you provide the expected result? in your initial data, you have `chr1` and `chr11` wherein `something like` you have `chr10` and `chr11`

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake, something must have went wrong when i wrote it, it should be better now. Where all are chr10 or chr11. So now the initial results and expected are correct.

Comment: your expected output is random, for example in `['chr10', 19010495, 19014658]`  the overlapping is more than 4000...should be 1000 max

Comment: Okay, again im sorry, i meant it as at least a 1000. so the more its overlapping the better, as long as it overlaps with a 1000. Of course it made sense to me so thanks for making me clarifying :-)

Comment: Im sorry :-(  but thanks for your help.

Comment: can you explain the logic of forming the groups?

Comment: Key1, 2 and 3 are coordinate intervals overlapping with more than 1000 as you pointed out, the goal is then to create a single dictionary for this group, in order to create a single new coordinate interval merging the information for these three keys, either by finding the most common values or taking the minimum and maximum. whereas key 4, 5 and 6 are already single coordinate intervals. The reason i want these as a dictionary is because its easier to create a pandas dataframe from that datastructure. Does it make sense?

Comment: in key 5 the difference btw max and min is more than 5000.... the group should not be split?

Comment: No key 5 shouldn't be split because its just a single key with a coordinate interval range. The overlap is only between each coordinate intervals, i.e. the values for the different. And since there is not other key with values overlapping with those in 5, it shouldn't be split. Again thanks for you to take the time. just to discuss this at least. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question probably fits better in a graph-based solution. There isn't anything preventing multiple ranges overlapping at differing intervals.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
  
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import groupby


def mapper(d, overlap=1000):
    """Each chromsomal coordinate must be interrogated
    to determine if it is within +/-overlap of any other
    
    Range within any other    Original Dictionary     Transcript
    value will match          key and chromosome      element from the list
    ------------------------  ----------------------  ----------
    (el-overlap, el+overlap), (dict-key, chromosome), el)
    """
    for key, ch in d.items():
        for el in ch[1:]:
            yield ((el-overlap, el+overlap), (key, ch[0]), el)

def sorted_mapper(d, overlap=1000):
    """Simply sort the mapper data by its first element
    """
    for r in sorted(mapper(d, overlap), key=lambda x: x[0]):
        yield r

def groups(iter_):
    previous = next(iter_)
    retval = [previous]
    for chrm in iter_:
        if previous[0][0] <= chrm[-1] <= previous[0][1]:
            retval.append(chrm)
        else:
            yield retval
            previous = chrm
            retval = [previous]
    yield retval

def reduce_phase1(iter_):
    for l in iter_:
        retval = {}
        for (minc, maxc), (key, lbl), chrm in l:
            x = retval.get(key,[lbl])
            x.append(chrm)
            retval[key] = x
        yield retval

def update_dict(d1, d2):
    retval = d1
    for key, value in d2.items():
        if key in d1.keys():
            retval[key].extend(value[1:])
    return retval

def reduce_phase2(iter_):
    retval = [next(iter_)]
    retval_keys = [set([k for k in retval[0].keys()])]
    for d in iter_:
        keyset = set([k for k in d.keys()])
        isnew = True
        for i, e in enumerate(retval_keys):
            if keyset <= e:
                isnew = False
                retval[i] = update_dict(retval[i], d)
        if isnew:
            retval.append(d)
            retval_keys.append(keyset)
    return retval

First_dict = {Key1: ['chr10', 19010495, 19014590, 19014064],
Key2: ['chr10', 19010495, 19014658],
Key3: ['chr10', 19010502, 19014641],
Key4: ['chr10', 37375766, 37377526],
Key5: ['chr10', 76310389, 76315990, 76312224, 76312963],
Key6: ['chr11', 14806147, 14814006]} 

New_list = [
        {
            "Key1": ['chr10', 19010495, 19014590, 19014064],
            "Key2": ['chr10', 19010495, 19014658],
            "Key3": ['chr10', 19010502, 19014641]
        },
        {"Key4": ['chr10', 37375766, 37377526]},
        {"Key5": ['chr10', 76310389, 76315990, 76312224, 76312963]},
        {"Key6": ['chr11', 14806147, 14814006]}
]

pprint(First_dict)
print('-'*40)
g = groups(sorted_ranges(First_dict))
p1 = reduce_phase1(groups(sorted_ranges(First_dict)))
p2 = reduce_phase2(p1)
pprint(p2)
```

## Output

```
{'Key1': ['chr10', 19010495, 19014590, 19014064],
 'Key2': ['chr10', 19010495, 19014658],
 'Key3': ['chr10', 19010502, 19014641],
 'Key4': ['chr10', 37375766, 37377526],
 'Key5': ['chr10', 76310389, 76315990, 76312224, 76312963],
 'Key6': ['chr11', 14806147, 14814006]}
----------------------------------------
[{'Key6': ['chr11', 14806147, 14814006]},
 {'Key1': ['chr10', 19010495, 19014064, 19014590],
  'Key2': ['chr10', 19010495, 19014658],
  'Key3': ['chr10', 19010502, 19014641]},
 {'Key4': ['chr10', 37375766, 37377526]},
 {'Key5': ['chr10', 76310389, 76312224, 76312963, 76315990]}]
```

## TLDR;

## Mapper output

The mapper emits a record for each dictionary key, and chromosomal element. Each record has an associated range in which its element can be matched.

```
((el-1000, el+1000), (dict-key, chromosome), el)
```

**(el-1000, el+1000)** is the range in which any other chromosomal element can match.

**(dict-key, chromosome)** the originating dictionary for this chromosome.

**el** is one element from the chromosomal coordinate.

```
((19009495, 19011495), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19010495)
((19013590, 19015590), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19014590)
((19013064, 19015064), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19014064)
((19009495, 19011495), ('Key2', 'chr10'), 19010495)
((19013658, 19015658), ('Key2', 'chr10'), 19014658)
((19009502, 19011502), ('Key3', 'chr10'), 19010502)
((19013641, 19015641), ('Key3', 'chr10'), 19014641)
((37374766, 37376766), ('Key4', 'chr10'), 37375766)
((37376526, 37378526), ('Key4', 'chr10'), 37377526)
((76309389, 76311389), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76310389)
((76314990, 76316990), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76315990)
((76311224, 76313224), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76312224)
((76311963, 76313963), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76312963)
((14805147, 14807147), ('Key6', 'chr11'), 14806147)
((14813006, 14815006), ('Key6', 'chr11'), 14814006)
```

**NOTE:** The output from the mapper is unsorted.

## Sort

We need to sort the transformed data using (el-1000, el+1000) as the key.
This will allow us to check if the next value is within the range of the previous value. Because the keys are in sorted order, we will be able to chain values together that are within the specified overlap.

```
((14805147, 14807147), ('Key6', 'chr11'), 14806147)
((14813006, 14815006), ('Key6', 'chr11'), 14814006)
((19009495, 19011495), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19010495)
((19009495, 19011495), ('Key2', 'chr10'), 19010495)
((19009502, 19011502), ('Key3', 'chr10'), 19010502)
((19013064, 19015064), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19014064)
((19013590, 19015590), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19014590)
((19013641, 19015641), ('Key3', 'chr10'), 19014641)
((19013658, 19015658), ('Key2', 'chr10'), 19014658)
((37374766, 37376766), ('Key4', 'chr10'), 37375766)
((37376526, 37378526), ('Key4', 'chr10'), 37377526)
((76309389, 76311389), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76310389)
((76311224, 76313224), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76312224)
((76311963, 76313963), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76312963)
((76314990, 76316990), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76315990)
```

## Group

Group the values that are within the specified overlap.
The lists that emerge will contain values from chromosomes
that are within the overlap of the previous chromosome.

```
[((14805147, 14807147), ('Key6', 'chr11'), 14806147)]
----------------------------------------
[((14813006, 14815006), ('Key6', 'chr11'), 14814006)]
----------------------------------------
[((19009495, 19011495), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19010495),
 ((19009495, 19011495), ('Key2', 'chr10'), 19010495),
 ((19009502, 19011502), ('Key3', 'chr10'), 19010502)]
----------------------------------------
[((19013064, 19015064), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19014064),
 ((19013590, 19015590), ('Key1', 'chr10'), 19014590),
 ((19013641, 19015641), ('Key3', 'chr10'), 19014641),
 ((19013658, 19015658), ('Key2', 'chr10'), 19014658)]
----------------------------------------
[((37374766, 37376766), ('Key4', 'chr10'), 37375766)]
----------------------------------------
[((37376526, 37378526), ('Key4', 'chr10'), 37377526)]
----------------------------------------
[((76309389, 76311389), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76310389)]
----------------------------------------
[((76311224, 76313224), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76312224),
 ((76311963, 76313963), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76312963)]
----------------------------------------
[((76314990, 76316990), ('Key5', 'chr10'), 76315990)]
----------------------------------------
```

## Reduce - Phase 1

Clean up data by removing engineered features.

```
{'Key6': ['chr11', 14806147]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key6': ['chr11', 14814006]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key1': ['chr10', 19010495],
 'Key2': ['chr10', 19010495],
 'Key3': ['chr10', 19010502]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key1': ['chr10', 19014064, 19014590],
 'Key2': ['chr10', 19014658],
 'Key3': ['chr10', 19014641]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key4': ['chr10', 37375766]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key4': ['chr10', 37377526]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key5': ['chr10', 76310389]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key5': ['chr10', 76312224, 76312963]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key5': ['chr10', 76315990]}
----------------------------------------
```

## Reduce - Phase 2

Aggregate the displaced dictionary keys with their
original dictionary. Append the values for the corresponding
chromosome when the dictionary keys match.

```
{'Key6': ['chr11', 14806147, 14814006]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key1': ['chr10', 19010495, 19014064, 19014590],
 'Key2': ['chr10', 19010495, 19014658],
 'Key3': ['chr10', 19010502, 19014641]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key4': ['chr10', 37375766, 37377526]}
----------------------------------------
{'Key5': ['chr10', 76310389, 76312224, 76312963, 76315990]}
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, nice use of generators. And thanks for your comments, which made it easier to follow all the steps. I don't have much experience with using graph-based methods. but ill definitely look into it. Thanks.