# How to make a layered bar chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

For this question, I was provided the following information.
[image]

[image]

Data in code form:

```
order_data = {'Alice': {5: 'chocolate'},
              'Bob': {9: 'vanilla'},
              'Clair': {7: 'strawberry'},
              'Drake': {10: 'chocolate' },
              'Emma': {82: 'vanilla'},
              'Alice': {70: 'strawberry'},
              'Emma': {42: 'chocolate'},
              'Ginger': {64: 'strawberry'} }
```

I was asked to make a bar graph detailing this data. The bar graph and the code used to make it using Altair is provided below.

```
import altair

data = altair.Data(customer=['Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire', 'Drake', 'Emma','Alice', 'Emma', 'Ginger'],
    cakes=[5,9,7,10,82,70,42,64],
    flavor=['chocolate', 'vanilla', 'strawberry','chocolate','vanilla','strawberry','chocolate','strawberry'])
chart = altair.Chart(data)
mark = chart.mark_bar()
enc = mark.encode(x='customer:N',y='cakes',color='flavor:N')
enc.display()
```

Graph: [image]

**My question is:** What is the best way to go about constructing this graph using matplotlib?

I know this isn't an unusual graph per say but it is unusual in the sense that I have not found any replications of this kind of graph. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproduction of the Altair graph with Matplotlib. Note that I had to modify the `order_data` dictionary because a dict cannot be defined with multiple keys at once (so I had to group the dictionary by key values). Also note that some optionally styling statements are included to also mimic the style of Altair.

The trick is to use the `bottom` keyword argument of the `ax.bar` function. The following image is obtained from the code below.

[image: bar stack altair like]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
order_data = {
    "Alice": {"chocolate": 5, "strawberry": 70},
    "Bob": {"vanilla": 9},
    "Clair": {"strawberry": 7},
    "Drake": {"chocolate": 10},
    "Emma": {"chocolate": 42, "vanilla": 82},
    "Ginger": {"strawberry": 64},
}

# init figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(2.5, 4))
colors = {"chocolate": "C0", "strawberry": "C1", "vanilla": "C2"}

# show a bar for each person
for person_id, (name, orders) in enumerate(order_data.items()):
    quantities = 0
    for order_id, (order, quantity) in enumerate(orders.items()):
        ax.bar(person_id, quantity, bottom=quantities, color=colors[order])
        quantities += quantity

# add legend
ax.legend([color for color in colors], bbox_to_anchor=(2.0, 1.0))

# remove top/right axes for style match
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.grid(axis="y", zorder=-1)

# ticks
ax.set_xticks(range(len(order_data)))
ax.set_xticklabels([name for name in order_data], rotation="vertical")
```

Comment: Is there anyway separate entries with the same customer may be placed on the same bar in the chart? For example say I had Emma purchase x amount of chocolate cakes, Alice purchases x amount of cakes, and then Emma comes back and purchases x amount of vanilla cakes. Is there anyway to have Emma's second purchase automatically be added to her existing data point on the chart without having to reorganize order_data so that her second order is included as a key value of her already existing location in the data? Thanks!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [group dictionary by keys with a defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this) so you can create a new plot with the newly added data. If you want to do it in a real update (animated) way, you should have a look at [creating animations with Matplotlib](https://towardsdatascience.com/animations-with-matplotlib-d96375c5442c).

Answer (score 2):

It has already been answered, but you can also graph it in pandas.plot.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire', 'Drake', 'Emma','Alice', 'Emma', 'Ginger'],
    'cakes':[5,9,7,10,82,70,42,64],
    'flavor':['chocolate', 'vanilla', 'strawberry','chocolate','vanilla','strawberry','chocolate','strawberry']})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.pivot(index='customer',columns='flavor', values='cakes').fillna(0)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]