# How to group keys by their value

Tags: python, dictionary, key, grouping

I need to group dictionary keys by their values and put it into а new dictionary. I'm expecting something like this:

```
groupedByValue = {'set1':[obj1],'set2':[obj2,obj3,obj6],'set3':[obj5,obj7]}
```

Source code:

```
dictionary = {'obj1':(10), 'obj2':(12), 'obj3':(12), 'obj5':(15), 'obj6':(12), 'obj7':(15)}
groupedByValue = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ()  around your dictionary values does nothing --- you can create a new dict by iterating the old one.

To get closer to your "wanted" output you can use a second dictionary for the value->key mapping:

```
dictionary = {'obj1':10, 'obj2':12, 'obj3':12, 'obj5':15, 'obj6':12, 'obj7':15}

groupedByValue = {}
keyVal = {}
i = 0
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    # increase i to get a new key for this value else use existing key
    if value not in keyVal:
        i += 1

    # for clarity - could directly do 
    # groupedByValue.setdefault(keyVal.setdefault(value, f"set{i}"), []).append(key)

    kk = keyVal.setdefault(value, f"set{i}")

    groupedByValue.setdefault(kk, []).append(key)
    

print(groupedByValue)
```

Output:

```
{'set1': ['obj1'], 'set2': ['obj2', 'obj3', 'obj6'], 'set3': ['obj5', 'obj7']}
```

---

Without that complication you can apply any of the answers of the dupes to facilitate the grouping:

Similar to part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/15751984/7505395 answer:

```
dictionary = {'obj1':10, 'obj2':12, 'obj3':12, 'obj5':15, 'obj6':12, 'obj7':15}

groupedByValue = {}
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    groupedByValue.setdefault(value,[]).append(key)        

print(groupedByValue)
```

Output:

```
{10: ['obj1'], 12: ['obj2', 'obj3', 'obj6'], 15: ['obj5', 'obj7']}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Patrick. This is what i need. I really must go deeper in learning of dictionary methods

Comment: I noticed some issues when I have tried to use code in real. The thing is I have a tuples as value with list inside. That is why I made my value tuples to  in order to make it hashable type. 

So the actual sourse code is:
```dictionary = {'obj1':([10,9,8]), 'obj2':([12,11,13]), 'obj3':([12,11,13]), 'obj5':([15,14,16]),  'obj6':([12,11,13]), 'obj7':([15,14,16])} 
```

And at this moment:

```if value not in keyVal:
        i += 1
```
I got "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: @Adrew you cannot use lists as keys. You can use str(list) as key:  `if str(value) not in keyVal: groupedByValue.setdefault(keyVal.setdefault(str(value), f"set{i}"), []).append(key)` - instead of str you also could use tuple for the lookupdict

Comment: Got it! I appreciate  it