# The best solution for receiving dictionary itemes whose value is unique

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose this is the dictionary:

```
dic = {a: 100, b: 100, c:90}
```

I would like to get a dictionary with items whose values are unique, In my example this is the result I want to get::

```
dic_b = {a: 100, c:90}
```

What will be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why ```a``` (key)'s value is ```unique```?   What is the logic here - please explain.  Please don't forget to post your attempted code.

Comment: Perhaps some of the answers to this question would work for you:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/15751979/2070046

Comment: I didn't understand your problems, I want to receive the items in the dictionary whose value is unique, I wrote what I expect to receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inverse the dictionary:

```py
dic = {"a": 100, "b": 100, "c": 90}

dic = {v: k for k, v in {v: k for k, v in dic.items()}.items()}
print(dic)
```

Prints:

```
{'b': 100, 'c': 90}
```

---

If you want to keep the key of first unique value, you can iterate over the items in reverse:

```py
dic = {"a": 100, "b": 100, "c": 90}

dic = {v: k for k, v in {v: k for k, v in reversed(dic.items())}.items()}
print(dic)
```

Prints:

```
{'c': 90, 'a': 100}
```

Comment: this is great although i would definitely wrap that code in a function because in a months time i would have no idea how it works lol

Comment: An excellent solution. Just explain to me please how it works. what removes the duplicates?

Comment: @Arica. Python dictionaries can contain only unique keys - so when you invert your original dictionary you practically remove duplicate values. Then you invert the dictionary second time to get keys, values in proper order.