# Python create list of dicts

Tags: python, json, list

I am new to python and I am trying to construct data structure from existing data.

I have following:

```
[
    {'UserName': 'aaa', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJD6X27YVK', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 8, 15, 56, 39, tzinfo=tzutc())},
    {'UserName': 'eee', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJD6QXMAKY', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 12, 30, 59, tzinfo=tzutc())}, 
    {'UserName': 'eee', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJDUARK6FV', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 16, 58, 38, tzinfo=tzutc())}
]
```

I need to get this:

```
{
  "aaa": [
    {'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJD6X27YVK', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 8, 15, 56, 39, tzinfo=tzutc())}],
  "eee": [
    {'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJD6QXMAKY', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 12, 30, 59, tzinfo=tzutc())}, 
    {'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJDUARK6FV', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 16, 58, 38, tzinfo=tzutc())}
   ]
}
```

I tried following:

```
list_per_user = {i['UserName']: copy.deepcopy(i) for i in key_list} 
for obj in list_per_user:     
   del list_per_user[obj]['UserName']
```

but I am missing array here. So in case of two keys per user I will have only last one with this. I don't know how to get the list I need per user.
Thanks!

Comment: So what did you try to solve this?

Comment: Use [Edit] to add your code to your question. Do not put it in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping Python dictionary keys as a list and create a new dictionary with this list as a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this)

Comment: why do you want a list of dictionaries? `AccessKeyId` seems to be a unique Id, which will make it a very good candidate for the key of a dictionary. Having a list will make things hard to find when you need to search for them. Imagine you want to retrieve the key `AKIAYWQTISJDUARK6FV` from `eee`. If you have a long list of dictionaries that will be very inneficient.

Comment: Because there can only be maximum of two access keys per user. If there is only one access key, generate new one, if there are two, get oldest one, deactivate it, delete and generate new one. I am totally OK to accept solution from someone else that would do what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an external dict that maps username -> list of entries.

```py
data = [
    {'UserName': 'aaa', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJD6X27YVK', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 8, 15, 56, 39, tzinfo=tzutc())},
    {'UserName': 'eee', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJD6QXMAKY', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 12, 30, 59, tzinfo=tzutc())}, 
    {'UserName': 'eee', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJDUARK6FV', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 24, 16, 58, 38, tzinfo=tzutc())}
]

new_data = {}
for entry in data:
    new_data.setdefault(entry["UserName"], []).append(
        {k: v for k, v in entry.items() if k != "UserName"}
    )

print(new_data)
```

Output (some fields hidden because I don't want to import those libraries in my repl, but they'll be there when you run it)

```py
{'aaa': [{'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJD6X27YVK', 'Status': 'Active'}],
 'eee': [{'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJD6QXMAKY', 'Status': 'Active'},
         {'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAYWQTISJDUARK6FV', 'Status': 'Active'}]}
```

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine, but I wanted to note that I personally tend to use `setdefault()` rather than `get()` in these situations as I think it makes the code a little cleaner

Comment: @JonSG didn't know that method existed, i've updated the code to reflect that. This is a better option especially in this case because the internals of the list can be mutated without changing its reference.

Comment: That is now exactly what I would have done :-)